# Viewing PDF through WebBrowser control shows adobe reader menus instead of pdf

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

There are some questions on here about getting a pdf to show up in a WPF app, I'm not having any issue with that. The issue is that when it does load up, there's all the default Adobe Reader toolbars and things clogging up the screen until I click options and set the file view mode to "Read Mode".

Screenshot:

[image]

Sometimes it opens up fine, but most of the time it opens like it does in that top pic.

I've looked around for default settings I might be able to change and for other people having this issue but have no luck.

I'm opening it in a pretty basic way:

```
this.webBrowser.Navigate("file:///" + "C:/code/example.pdf");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.